# How to get the max value in a nested dictionary and key that contains it?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary and I get the max value in every nested dictionary, but also I want to get the key that contains it.
How can I get the key?

Dictionary:

```
{0: {'No': 0.0008701660440099657, 'Yes': 0.00041988149400856126},
 1: {'No': 0.00030532988393349125, 'Yes': 0.0004650428587258767},
 2: {'No': 0.0009029060356133256, 'Yes': 0.0007394058270439404},
 3: {'No': 5.692242884555282e-05, 'Yes': 0.0005919332682707075},
 4: {'No': 0.00015013263827995824, 'Yes': 0.00013704067699909492},
 5: {'No': 0.0006475515553117131, 'Yes': 0.000398292472360402},
 6: {'No': 0.00015299971518718442, 'Yes': 0.000636069387240845},
 7: {'No': 0.0003432474070424342, 'Yes': 0.0001701115953231753},
 8: {'No': 0.00029659442779058097, 'Yes': 0.0001243229615986186},
 9: {'No': 0.0002346339088222795, 'Yes': 4.1301441738705087e-05}}
```

Code that gets max value:

```
    for i in range(len(res_dic)):
        print(max(res_dic[i].values()))
```

Expected output:

```
No, 0.0008701660440099657
```

Comment: Are you creating the `dict`? If so, I would recommend swapping the `key` and `value` pairs, i.e. make your current `values` your `keys` and your current `keys` your ``values`. That way, given that the values are unique, you can easily get the desired information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `max` with `key`:

```
for i in range(len(res_dic)):
    x = max(res_dic[i], key=res_dic[i].get)
    print(x, res_dic[i][x])
```

Output:

```
No 0.0008701660440099657
Yes 0.0004650428587258767
No 0.0009029060356133256
Yes 0.0005919332682707075
No 0.00015013263827995824
No 0.0006475515553117131
Yes 0.000636069387240845
No 0.0003432474070424342
No 0.00029659442779058097
No 0.0002346339088222795
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you want is to get the max value out of all numbers in that nested dict... you can convert all of them into tuples in a generator and apply max on them:

```py
>>> max((o[t], t, n) for n, o in res_dic.items() for t in ('Yes', 'No'))
(0.0009029060356133256, 'No', 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
maxi = -1000000
keyi = None

for k,v in d.items(): 
    for k1, v1 in v.items():
        if v1>maxi:
            maxi = v1
            keyi = k1
print(keyi, maxi)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the key parameter of [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) to find the maximum of the items by it's value:

```
from operator import itemgetter

res_dic = {0: {'No': 0.0008701660440099657, 'Yes': 0.00041988149400856126},
           1: {'No': 0.00030532988393349125, 'Yes': 0.0004650428587258767},
           2: {'No': 0.0009029060356133256, 'Yes': 0.0007394058270439404},
           3: {'No': 5.692242884555282e-05, 'Yes': 0.0005919332682707075},
           4: {'No': 0.00015013263827995824, 'Yes': 0.00013704067699909492},
           5: {'No': 0.0006475515553117131, 'Yes': 0.000398292472360402},
           6: {'No': 0.00015299971518718442, 'Yes': 0.000636069387240845},
           7: {'No': 0.0003432474070424342, 'Yes': 0.0001701115953231753},
           8: {'No': 0.00029659442779058097, 'Yes': 0.0001243229615986186},
           9: {'No': 0.0002346339088222795, 'Yes': 4.1301441738705087e-05}}

by_value = itemgetter(1)

maximum = (max(d.items(), key=by_value) for d in res_dic.values())
result = max(maximum, key=by_value)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
('No', 0.0009029060356133256)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Val_Res_dic = res_dic.values()
for dic in Val_Res_dic:
    print(max(dic, key=dic.get), ',', max(dic.values()))
```

Comment: It would be good if you provide additional explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Expand the sub-dicts as key-value tuples, and use the second item as the key for the `max` function:

```
max((p for d in res_dic.values() for p in d.items()), key=lambda t: t[1])
```

This returns:

```
('No', 0.0009029060356133256)
```